# Why are div elements not re-indexed after removing one of them with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, removechild

I want to remove a `div` with the `index == 0` each time I click on one of the elements with the class `.slide`.

It works the first time, but when I try again, the code tries to remove the element that has been previously removed, but I can still log the element to the console.

I thought that index "0" will be assigned to the next `div` sharing the same class, so the next time I click, this next `div` would be deleted.

What am I missing here?

Here is my code:

```js
    let slides = document.querySelectorAll(".slide")
     
    slides.forEach((el) => {
        el.addEventListener("click", () => {
            // remove the first div 
            slides[0].remove() 

            // the element above has been removed, but I still can log it out (?)
            // and it seems to keep the index [0]       
            console.log(slides[0])
        })
    })
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll: _"The Document method querySelectorAll() returns a **static (not live)** NodeList representing a list of the document's elements that match the specified group of selectors."_ (**bold** by me)

Comment: `remove` removes the element from the DOM, not the array.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it is a way to go. Do you have any ideas on how to manipulate a set of divs ( delete one of them, add one to the collection ) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do exactly what you expect - and will only get from the **live** `HTMLCollection` that `getElementsByClassName` returns:

```js
let slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slide")

for (const slide of slides) {
  slide.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // remove the first div 
    slides[0].remove()
    console.log(slides[0])
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">0</div>
<div class="slide">1</div>
<div class="slide">2</div>
<div class="slide">3</div>
<div class="slide">4</div>
<div class="slide">5</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, indeed I started playing with the live HTMLCollections and it works. BTW, I am wondering why "for of" loop works and "forEach" doesn't on HTMLCollections? Best, P.

Comment: `for...of` works with anything iterable, whereas calling `.forEach` **on** an object means that object does have to have that method. NodeLists have `forEach`, whereas HTMLCollections don't. That is just one advantage of `for...of` - it's also more readable, and doesn't require a callback function.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have deleted the element from the DOM, but have not removed it from the array. Try using the `shift` array method to remove the first element that you are deleting.

```
slides.forEach((el)=>{
    el.addEventListener("click",()=>{
        slides.shift().remove();
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have just checked. The code you have provided throws this in the console: Uncaught TypeError: slides. shift is not a function. I believe it has something to do with what @CBroe wrote, that querySelector NodeList is not live, and as such cannot be manipulated.

Comment: The reason is the same `forEach` won't work on `HTMLCollection` - `NodeList` is **not an array** and as such, won't support most of the `Array.prototype` methods. `shift()` is one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your feedback, and the research I did ( on live and static node lists ) I came up with the following solution to my question. As you can see I am not using a querySelection nodelist anymore as this type is static. Instead, I went for a getElementsByClassName HTML collection.  What do you think of this? Thanks for your precious support!

```js
let sliderCollection = document.getElementsByClassName("slider") // HTML COLLECTION

let arrayCollection =[] 
arrayCollection = Array.from(sliderCollection) // HTML COLLECTION turned into an array
console.log("initial number of divs:",arrayCollection.length) // initial number of divs

arrayCollection.forEach( (el)=>{
    el.addEventListener('click',()=>{
   sliderCollection[0].remove() // remove always the first element
   arrayCollection = Array.from(sliderCollection) // refill the array with the updated number of divs
   console.log(arrayCollection.length) // keep track of the current number of divs
    })
})
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  
  .slider {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border: solid 2px black;
    font-size: 3em;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="slider">0</div>
            <div class="slider">1</div>
            <div class="slider">2</div>
            <div class="slider">3</div>
            <div class="slider">4</div>
            <div class="slider">5</div>
          </div>
```